# Оптимизация сервера MySQL

Tags: mysql

Всем привет, у меня есть несколько вопросов:

1. Как узнать из командной строки какой тип таблиц используется в БД? (MyISAM, InnoDB, BlackHole...)
2. Дайте, пожалуйста, ссылки на видео, статьи о тонкой настройке сервера MySQL.
3. Если на продакшене все таблицы хранятся в MyISAM можно ли безболезненно перейти на InnoDB? Или лучше не трогать?

Comment: П.1 какая-то конкретная таблица, или сводная справка?

Answer (score 1):

1) Можно через show table status http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-table-status.html

3) Если не ошибаюсь, то тут есть 2 основных момента:
 - в innodb нету полнотекстовых индексов, если использовали match, то работать не будет.
 - для каждой таблицы необходимо создать primary key, т.к. они используются для построения индексов, если их не создать, то innodb сама создаст скрытый primary key

А так несколько путей для перехода:
 - через alter table сменить тип движка
 - создать таблицы и перенести в них данные

PS конечно же вначале нужно понять так уж ли необходима смена движка